# Limit to sound playout using AndEngine

Tags: java, android, audio, andengine

Is there a limit to how long a sound can be played out for in AndEngine? I'm trying to get my app to play a sound and it's only playing about the first 6 seconds of the tune. Is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late answer but for longer sounds you should be using Andengine's Music class, not Sound.  Sound is for shorter sound effects I believe.

Answer (score 2):

Are you playing more than five sounds and using the default constructor?  If so, perhaps one of the streams is being cut off to play a new sound.

Try initializing SoundManager with more simultaneous streams.

```
public SoundManager(final int pMaxSimultaneousStreams)
```

Comment: It would just end after five seconds not dependent on whether there was a sound following it. I've since discovered that there's a music and a sound class, the music class plays out for longer. I guess the sound class is for meant for smaller sounds?

Comment: SoundPool appears to have a size limit -- perhaps 1048576 bytes?  I couldn't find confirmation of this in the documentation though.